# SQL count items outside of group by filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, group-by

Suppose I have the following table:

```
Product A    Product B
Water        Soda
Water        Soda
Water        Eggs
Water        Apples
```

I'm trying to count the product combinations and the number of each product so that my results are:

```
Product A   Product B   Combination Product A Count Product B Count
Water        Soda               2                 4               2
Water        Eggs               1                 4               1
Water        Apples             1                 4               1
```

Unfortunately, once I group the products, I can't get the individual counts. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT [ProductA], [ProductB], Count(*) as ComboCount
FROM [ProductCombinations]
GROUP BY [ProductA], [ProductB]
Order by ComboCount Desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works very well and is clean I think:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Product A], [Product B], 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Product A], [Product B]) ComboCount, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Product A]) [Product A Count], 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Product B]) [Product B Count]
FROM [ProductCombinations]
ORDER BY ComboCount DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could count each product independently, and join those to your current query:

```
SELECT   p.[ProductA], p.[ProductB], COUNT(*) As CombotCount, 
         ProductA_Count, ProductB_Count
FROM     [ProductCombinations] p
JOIN     (SELECT   [ProductA], COUNT(*) AS ProductA_Count
          FROM     [ProductCombinations]
          GROUP BY [ProductA]) a ON p.[ProductA] = a.[ProductA]
JOIN     (SELECT   [ProductB], COUNT(*) AS ProductB_Count
          FROM     [ProductCombinations]
          GROUP BY [ProductB]) a ON p.[ProductA] = b.[ProductB]
GROUP BY [ProductA], [ProductB]
ORDER BY ComboCount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

A subquery can do this. 
(i is for "inner", o for "outer")

```
SELECT o.[ProductA], o.[ProductB], Count(*) as ComboCount, 
  (select count(*) from ProductCombinations.i where i.ProductA =   o.ProductA) as ACount,
  (select count(*) from ProductCombinations.i where i.ProductB = o.ProductB) as BCount
FROM [ProductCombinations] o
GROUP BY o.[ProductA], i.[ProductB]
Order by o.ComboCount Desc
```